# Female always hanging off males throat

Tags: dogs, behavior, training

We have two dogs - brother and sister from different litters. Albert is 20 months and Ursula is 1 year and was the runt of her litter. Ursula joined us when she was 3 months old and Albert was 11 months. From the moment she got here, she's played very rough with him. She is always hanging off of his throat. How do we get her to stop with the throat? Thanks